# ORA-12514 after restoring server from snapshot

Tags: oracle, ora-12514

We have a series of Amazon Web Services servers running Amazon Linux and Oracle XE, which is used by a local app. OracleXE installs and runs just fine, our app can connect to the DB, everything is great.

For one of our particular servers, we needed to shut it down and archive it. Today, I need to bring it online. This is done by setting up a new AWS instance, creating a new virtual hard drive from backup snapshot, setting up a new public IP for the server and changing DNS settings to that the old domain points to the new IP, connecting up the restored virtual drive as the main drive, and starting it up.

OracleXE doesn't want to work. Using sqlplus to connector to localhost:1521/XE produces "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor".

This system was working just fine when I snapshotted it and archived it the first time, and I hadn't changed any settings since restoring it. Everything should be exactly the same, so why is OracleXE now not working?

The listener.ora and tnsnames.ora had the host defined using the server's public domain name. I tried changing that to localhost, but it's still not working.

The only things I can think of that will be different are the server's public IP address, and the "rsa2 key fingerprint" (what Putty complains about due to the SSH key being the same but it being a new AWS instance). All the advice I've seen so far is for fixing config errors for ORA-12514 when setting up a new system or after restarting, but this is a system that was working fine but has been restored from snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your listener uses dynamic instance registration.

For that to work, your listener must be listening to the default port (1521) or your instance must use the local listener parameter that defines the address of the listener where the instance should register it's existence.

So, check your local_listener parameter, check the servers tnsnames.ora and listener.ora. Also check your clients tnsnames.ora, it should point to your new server and listener.

Comment: The DB and the listener are on the same system.

I wasn't aware that the database had its own settings to determine how it contacted the listener. Googling "local_listener" unearthed this info:

Default value: (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)>(PORT=1521)) where hostname is the network name of the local host.

The problem was simply that I hadn't allowed the server's new public IP through its own firewall, and I wasn't aware it was trying to use the public IP.